# How to restore database tables from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

hi everybody i'm new to Ruby on Rails...
I created a Rails Application for that i created a database called 'cart' in MySQL database by using rake command. but unfortunately my database got crashed. right now there are no databases including older ones also deleted.
please help me, how can i get my all databases from MySQL s/w. is there any command to restore the crashed data.

Thanks

Comment: `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have backup it could be hard. You can remove database, create another and rake db:migrate but it will only create a structure for you and will not restore data. 
You can try to reproduce your records from rails logs but it will be a lot of work

What do you mean by database crashed?